# How to only deregister Wordpress stylesheet for non-logged in users?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I use the following code in my `functions.php` to disable the `dashicons.min.css` file from the frontend. It works fine, but how can I use that action only for visitors, who are not currently signed in to WordPress?

The reason is that the WordPress admin bar at the top is broken, if the dashicons css file is not available.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles',     'my_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_deregister_styles()    { 
   wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' ); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the function `is_user_logged_in()` which comes with WordPress. Read about it at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/.

So your code would be:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles',        'my_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_deregister_styles()    {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) 
        wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons'); 
}
```